# Visibility private fields on Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a public class in my project, using C# and Visual Studio 2017. I added some private fields to the class and assembly project. When I view my class on Object Explorer, I see all private fields.

[class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmN2Z.jpg)

[Object Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LWjT.jpg)

Is this a bug in VS or is this how it should be?

Comment: This is how it should be. You can see a little lock at the icon of your fields, which indicates that these are private

Comment: `private` is "to be used only be other members within this class", not "hide this from programmers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Info on Acces Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

All you do by setting them private is hiding them from access, they still show up in the resources, so this is intended behaviour.

If you want to hide the code itself, you could put it in a library and import that library into the project.